# How to stop a BufferedReader after a certain amount of time in Android

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I've got a thread that opens a socket that sends data to a server. The server may send data back depending if someone is at the work station. However I'm trying to put a timeout on the `BufferedReader` so that after 30 seconds it continues saying the response was null.

```
//Receive Response
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
response = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
    response.append(line);
}
```

This is my `BufferedReader`, pretty standard, I've looked at a bunch of timers and other posts but haven't found a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call [`setSoTimeout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) on your socket instance.

Itt will raise a `SocketTimeoutException` when the timeout is reached. Wrap your reading logic in a try-catch block, catch  that exception and handle it as you wish.

Something like this:

```
try {
    socket.setSoTimeout(30000);

    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
        response.append(line);
    }
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
    // timeout reached
} catch (Exception e) {
    // something else happened
} finally {
    // some general processing
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it without disconnecting the socket.

Comment: @Demonic218 From its docs: "If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, **though the Socket is still valid**."

Comment: Sorry, that previous comment was abit of a mix up. I've got code after the buffereader to sort of read the response, for example approved, declined and after 30 seconds it should be null. However when the timeout happens it seems to jump right down to the exception instead of reading the response.

Comment: @Demonic218 The response is still in the `response` variable when the exception occurs, you can process it in the `catch` block then, or in a `finally` block.